# How to fix "net.minecraft.util.SessionLock$ExceptionWorldConfict already locked" error?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am getting this error when trying to start my server:

> [main/FATAL]: Failed to start the minecraft server
> net.minecraft.util.SessionLock$ExceptionWorldConfict: /home/minecraft/lobby/./world/session.lock: already locked (possibly by other Minecraft instance?)

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either another server or local session is already running that game world. Check to see you don't already have a server running the background or any Minecraft instances already running the world.

See this [forum post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/3074410-when-i-open-my-server-it-says-this) for more information.

> Make sure you stopped the server completely
> (Check Task Manager for running Java instances and close these)
> If it is not working, backup and delete the session.lock from your worlds-folder

If you are using some sort of hosting service to run your server, you may need to contact the service provider for assistance.  It's possible something could have gone wrong and now the server lock is out of sync.